# Installing a application binary on iphone through mac?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a application binary (.app) file on my MacBook... I dont have the source file. Is there any possible way that I can install the application on my iPhone through my MacBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a the mobile provisioning profile used to build the app, and the provisioning profile includes your iPhone's device ID, then yes. This is known as "Ad-Hoc Deployment".

Otherwise, no, Apple forces you through the App Store.